# Unsupported Engine error when trying to install hardhat

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal, hardhat

I am having difficulties finding a fix here... I'm trying to install hardhat but it says i need a verion of node higher than 12.0 ... which I clearly have?

Any help would be much appreciated!! Thank you!

```
    Laptop:full-mint-website Preeminent$ npm i -D hardhat
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'hardhat@2.9.9',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^16.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.6.0', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.4: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

up to date, audited 2196 packages in 16s

115 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

71 vulnerabilities (15 low, 18 moderate, 36 high, 2 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: Which version of node you are using? The error says you are using v17.6.0 where as the supported versions are `'^12.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^16.0.0'`

Comment: oh i thought it meant any version above those... How can i install a previous version of node? Thanks in advance and appreciate the help!

Comment: You can use node version manager https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. It gives flexibility to install multiple node versions